# Error when using auto_publish = true in stream publish

Tags: facebook

I have a application, and i want to publish stream without prompt so i made auto_publish Boolean as true but still application shows prompt box.

Answer (score 0):

this maybe because your application must be granted with permission publish_stream

```
<fb:prompt-permission perms="read_stream,publish_stream">Would you like our application to read from and post to your News Feed?</fb:prompt-permission>
```